# Creating a number based on given conditions

Tags: list-manipulation

In the grade 7 math curriculum here in Alberta we teach divisibility.  I'm trying to write a program to create questions based on the idea of a student being given say, 4 digits,  and then choosing one of their own to create say,  "the largest number divisible by 5".

I have a few simple ideas.
Get a list of 4 numbers...

```
RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 4]
```

Arrange them

```
Permutations[list]
```

Turn them into numbers...

```
FromDigits /@ Permutations[list]
```

I'm sure there must be an elegant way to use Mathematica to do this.
I'd need to have the original 4 digits and the answer so I could create the question under program control.

I.E.    Given the digits  9, 0, 0, 2   and 1 other digit of your choice,  create the largest 5 digit number you can that is divisible by 5.

I'd appreciate any hints or suggestions.

Comment: That doesn't look like a bad start.  Have you tried writing it like that yourself?  What problems did you run into, or where was the implementation lacking?

Comment: Hi,  I could find the maximum given a list,  but didn't know how to "elegantly"  pick the extra digits , create the possible numbers, and find the largest.   Often the case with my skills,  I'm learning but often need a bit of help.  Getting help here is such a great source of assistance.

Comment: How are the students assumed to go about solving such a task?

Comment: @ssch Trying all permutations by hand, obviously. It's called "sadism" :)

Comment: Well,  they would all be VERY SIMPLE problems,  I.E.  a number divisible by 2, 5, 10, 9, 3.   Just those that have nice divisibility tests... so, hopefully it's not sadism!!  It's a "standard" problem for this topic, that doesn't make it right, but it's what I have to "teach"....

Comment: @TomDeVries From Martin Gardner:     _Find the one and only 10-digit number such that :

    1) All digits are different, and

    2) the number formed by the first N digits is divisible by N._

Comment: HI,  wow,  that's a nice question,  and uses a lot of the stuff on divisibility we study.  But it sure requires a lot of testing!!    I think  3 8 1 6 5 4 7 2 9 0  fits the bill?  Thanks again for your work on the question,  my "generator" is in a package and will get used every day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this?

```
f[initialNbrOfdigits_, extradigits_, divisor_] := Module[{sol = -Infinity, s},
   While[sol == -Infinity, 
         s   = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, initialNbrOfdigits];
         sol = Max@Select[FromDigits /@  Flatten[Permutations[Join[s, #]] & /@ 
                              Tuples[Range[0, 9], {extradigits}], 1], Divisible[#, divisor] &]];
   Column@{Row[{"Given the digits ", s, " and ", extradigits, 
                " more of your choice, create the largest ", extradigits + initialNbrOfdigits, 
                " digit number you can that is divisible by ", divisor}],
           Row[{"Solution: ", sol}]}
   ];
f[3, 2, 773]
```

> Given the digits {9,9,4} and 2 more of your choice, create the largest 5 digit number you can that is divisible by 773
>
> Solution: 98944

**Edit**

With a small modification to avoid considering numbers with leading zeroes, you could ask also for the minimum:

```
f[initialNbrOfdigits_, extradigits_, divisor_, f_] := 
  Module[{sol = -Infinity, s}, 
   While[sol == -Infinity, 
    s = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, initialNbrOfdigits];
    sol = f@Select[FromDigits /@ Flatten[Permutations[Join[s, #]] & /@ 
                   Tuples[Range[0, 9], {extradigits}], 1], Divisible[#, divisor] && # >= 
                                                   10^(extradigits + initialNbrOfdigits - 1) &]];
   Column@{Row[{"Given the digits ", s, " and ", extradigits, 
                " more of your choice, create the " , f, " ", extradigits + initialNbrOfdigits, 
                " digit number you can that is divisible by ", divisor}], 
           Row[{"Solution: ", sol}]}];

f[3, 2, 18, Min]
```

> Given the digits {8,2,2} and 2 more of your choice, create the Min 5 digit number you can that is divisible by 18
>   Solution: 12258

Comment: Thanks!  That looks brilliant.  I'll see if I get any other answers but I can use this right now.  I know it probably wouldn't happen often, but how would I check to make sure I actually get a number?    I.E.  how do I check list s to insure it has at least 1 non-zero digit?   Thanks for your help,  that last line is so compact, I'll have to go through carefully to see what's happening, but that's definitely what I needed!

Comment: @TomDeVries The new code address your concerns

Comment: Thanks again, very useful,  and I'll use the "minimum" question as well.  Already used this today to create a set of questions for a student.  Much appreciated!!